# CastToDouble Spatialite doesn't cast negative numbers

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite, spatialite

I am using a spatialite database. I need to cast to double a negative number (this number is a text).

When I do `SELECT CastToDouble("-5.84")`, I get a NULL..

How can i Cast a negative number , in text format, to a Double?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use SQLite's built-in [cast expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#castexpr):

```
SELECT CAST('-5.84' AS REAL)
```